# How can I check the type of a parameter implementing an interface?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, interface, micronaut

I am using dependency injection to inject an implementation of an interface. I would like to make it possible to call a method on the injected type with a parameter whose implementation is also being injected and based on an Interface.
**Example**:

- `SessionInterface` is implemented by `Session_A` and `Session_B`
- `ConfigInterface` is implemented by `Config_A` and `Config_B`
- `Session_A` should only use objects of `Config_A`, same with `_B`

In the application an implementation of a session is injected (without a config). Later, an implementation of config can be injected, to use it as a parameter for the session's method `run(ConfigInterface config)`
In this method I'd like to make sure that the given parameter's type is the one corresponding to the session.

Should I use `getClass()`, `instanceof` or something else to check this?

Comment: In your sessionInterface you can define template like <T extends ConfigInterface> and then in implementation class of Session_A you can directly use Config_A in run method and you wont even need to use instanceof or getclass(). Otherwise instanceof is better

Answer (score 0):

(You'll find a lot of discussion in this problem space.  I'm still improving my understanding of this type of problem, and I welcome any improvements to this answer.)

One possible answer is to use a PECS type pattern (PECS stands for Producer Extends and Consumer Super; see [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)).

Here is a code example:

```
interface PECS_Supplier<T> {
    T supply();
}

interface PECS_Consumer<T> {
    void consume(T value);
}

public class PECS_Engine {
    public <T> void process(PECS_Supplier<? extends T> supplier, PECS_Consumer<? super T> consumer) {
        T nextValue;
        while ( (nextValue = supplier.supply()) != null )  {
            consumer.consume(nextValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Note the "? extends T" and "? super T" in the process method.